# Prove an odd group's subgroup is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Assume that $G$ is odd and $|G|=3|H|$  Prove that $H$ is normal in $G$

An hint is given for the solution as follows:
let $\ a \in G\ s.t. a \not\in H$

Define $\phi:H\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\ s.t.\ \phi(h)=0$ if $\ haH=aH$, $\phi(h)=1$ if $\ haH=a^2H$

Then $\phi(H)=\{0\}$ so $\phi(H)=\{0\}=Ker(\phi)$ so $H$ is normal.

My misunderstanding:
Previously I had shown that if $a \not\in H$, there are 3 unique cosets of $H$ in $G$ ($H,aH,a^2H$). So if $h \in H$, and $\phi(h)=0$

$$(*)\implies haH=aH\implies h\in aH \implies H\cap aH\neq \emptyset\implies aH=H$$

Which is obviously a contradiction. Could help me understand

1. Why is statement $(*)$ not true? (Edit: this has been made clear to me now)
2. How would I show that $\phi(h)=0\ \forall h \in H$ ?

Comment: You assume $|G|=3|H|$ and you have to prove it?

Comment: My mistake! edited

Comment: $haH = aH$ does not imply $h \in aH$. It implies $ha \in aH$, which means $h \in aHa^{-1}$.

Comment: but it is a property of cosets that $aH=H\ iff\ a \in H$. If it doesn't apply, is that because $aH$ is not necessarily a group?

Comment: Correct, $aH$ is not a group unless $a \in H$, so that property does not apply. Regarding your second question, have you shown that $\phi$ is a homomorphism? If so, note that $\phi(H)$ must be a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_2$, and there are only two possibilities since $\mathbb Z_2$ only has two subgroups.

Comment: Yeah, I've shown $\phi$ is a homomorphism. So $phi(H)\subset \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $phi(H) = \{0,1\}\ or\ \{0\}$. but $|\phi(H)|$ divides $|H|$ so $phi(H) = \{0\}$. Thanks for the help

Comment: No, $\phi(H)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_2$, so $|\phi(H)|$ divides $|\mathbb Z_2| = 2$. What can you say about $|H / \text{ker}(\phi)|$?

Comment: Suppose $\phi :G \rightarrow G'$ and $H$ is a subgroup of G. let $\phi_H$ denote teh restriction of $\phi$ to the elements of $H$. Then $\phi_H$ is a homomorphism of $H$ onto $\phi(H)$. Suppose $|Ker\phi_H|=t \implies \phi $ is a $t$-to-1 mapping so $|\phi (H)|t =|H|$ This is true in general, not just for this specific case of $H, \phi$.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you were saying. Indeed, $|H| = |\ker(\phi)| \cdot |\text{im}(\phi)| = |\ker(\phi)| \cdot |\phi(H)|$, hence $|\phi(H)|$ is odd, essentially the same as what I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have verified that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, recall that $H / \ker(\phi) \cong \text{im}(\phi)$, so $|H| / |\ker(\phi)| = |\text{im}(\phi)|$. Now $|G|$ is odd, so $|H|$ is odd, so $|H| / |\ker(\phi)|$ is odd, which means that $|\text{im}(\phi)|$ is odd. Since $\text{im}(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_2$, its order must be $1$ or $2$, and of these possibilities, only $1$ is odd. Therefore $|\text{im}(\phi)| = 1$, so $|\ker(\phi)| = |H|$, so $\ker(\phi) = H$.